# C# how to call the function from another function in .cs

Tags: c#, treeview, call

1.C_backupTPForm.cs

```
private void C_B_After_Click_for_nodecheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e){

 DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(e.Node.FullPath);

            DirectoryInfo[] directories = rootDir.GetDirectories();

            int i = 0;

            foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
            {

                if (e.Node.Nodes[i++].Checked == true)
                {
                    AL_ftp_filepath.Add(ftp_filePath.ToString());

                }

            }

}
```

===========================================================================
2.C_BackupTPForm.cs

```
private void C_B_backupNowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

*********** C_B_After_Click_for_nodecheck(sender,);************// I wanna call this function here but, I can't
            C_R_treeViewShow();

}
```

There are 2 classes in a same project. and there are each functions in each class.
I wanna call `C_B_After_Click_for_nodecheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)` from `private void C_B_backupNowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`. but, It has a problem about `TreeViewEventArgs e`. Because `C_B_backupNowButton_Click` has another type of `EventArgs`. Is there the way to call the function?

Comment: Make a separate method (with just the sender as parameter; or not even that, looks like you don't use the sender) and call that from both click event handlers?

Comment: I tried..but I can't.. 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs' doesn't have the constructor using 0 ValType.

Comment: `C_B_After_Click_for_nodecheck(sender,e)` have you tried that Yona Kim..?

Comment: It says 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs' doesn't have the constructor using 0 of ValType'

Comment: DJ KRAZE, Yes I have. but different type of eventArgs.

Comment: Corak // No I don't need object sender. and How to create TreeViewEventArgs? I tried TreeviewEventArgs e = new TreeviewEventArgs(); but, It has lots of errors.

Comment: @YonaKim - You don't need `TreeViewEventArgs`, you need a `TreeNode`. Look at Mauricio Gracias answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
public NodeCheck(TreeNode node) 
{
    DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(node.FullPath);
    DirectoryInfo[] directories = rootDir.GetDirectories();

    int i = 0;

    foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
    {

        if (e.Node.Nodes[i++].Checked == true)
        {
            AL_ftp_filepath.Add(ftp_filePath.ToString());

        }

    }

}
private void C_B_After_Click_for_nodecheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
     NodeCheck(e.Node);
}

private void C_B_backupNowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     TreeNode node ; 

     node = //Code to get the code that you need/selected one
     NodeCheck(node);
     C_R_treeViewShow();
}
```

To add a node you can do this

```
string childText = "child" ;

C_B_treeView.BeginUpdate()
C_B_treeView.Nodes.Add(childText);

C_B_treeView.EndUpdate();
```

If you want all your nodes to be visible after updating them

```
C_B_treeView.ExpandAll();
```

Comment: What I wanna do is to check all nodes whether nodes are checked or not. According to ur source, I can apply for special node I designated, right?

Comment: @YonaKim for "special node" you mean a class that inherits from TreeNode ?

Comment: My treeView name is C_B_treeView. how can I create TreeNode?

Comment: And also, C_B_After_Click_for_nodecheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) isn't needed. anyfunction doesn't call it in ur source.

Comment: private void C_B_After_Click_for_nodecheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) is not Eventhandler. I created it.

Comment: @YonaKim my answer is based on your posted code, if your source code had any flaws, like a function that is not beeing called, they are going to be reflected on my answer as well

Comment: YonaKim I have added an example that shows how to add Nodes to the treeView

Comment: I should have explained my situation. I am sorry that I shouldn't have. My treevies is my computer's directory. It's already made. and I wanna check my directory_treeview whether its checkbox is checked or not if I click some button.